# Torchscript trace "must be on the current device" error despite model and input both being on the same device

Tags: pytorch, torchscript

I am failing to run torch.jit.trace despite my best effort, encountering `RuntimeError: Input, output and indices must be on the current device`

I have a (fairly complex) model which I have already put on GPU, along with a set of inputs, also on GPU. I can verify that all input tensors and model parameters & buffers are on the same device:

```
(Pdb) {p.device for p in self.parameters()}
{device(type='cuda', index=0)}
(Pdb) {p.device for p in self.buffers()}
{device(type='cuda', index=0)}
(Pdb) in_ = (<several tensors here>)
(Pdb) {p.device for p in in_}
{device(type='cuda', index=0)}
(Pdb) torch.cuda.current_device()
0
```

I can certify the model runs and the output is on the correct device:

```
(Pdb) self(*in_).device
device(type='cuda', index=0)
```

Despite all this, tracing fails:

```
(Pdb) generator_script = torch.jit.trace(self, example_inputs=in_)
*** RuntimeError: Input, output and indices must be on the current device
```

1. I understand about inputs and outputs, but what are these "indices"
   that must also be on the same device?
2. What other elements that I am
   not accounting for could be causing trace to fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not yet mapping the device during the loading process, doing so could be the solution.[1] That is, mapping the device should happen during `jit.load`, not as a simple call of `.to(device)` after `jit.load` has already finished. See [this page for more info](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.jit.load.html).

As an example of what to do:

```py
model = jit.load("your_traced_model.pt", map_location=torch.device("cuda"))
```

This is different from how it works for typical/non-JIT models, where you can simply do:

```py
model = some_model_creation_function()
_ = model.to(torch.device("cuda"))
```

1 = this does not currently work [for the MPS device](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/88820).

Comment: Ah, this was something I did notice was missing from my code when working with a different model. Interesting to note that was also the cause of this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After hard-coding the trace command into my code, I was able to get a more precise stack trace which let me to this piece of code, which I simplified for ease of reading:

```
B, L, C, H, W = inp_seq.shape
ref_seq = torch.repeat_interleave(
    ref_seq.squeeze(dim=1),
    repeats=L,
    dim=0,
)
```

During normal execution, `L` evaluates to a python `int`, but using pdb I was able to determine that L became a `Tensor`, which should be ok, except that this tensor was on cpu, and was causing the error.

Forcibly converting `L` to int was sufficient to overcome this error:

```
B, L, C, H, W = inp_seq.shape
ref_seq = torch.repeat_interleave(
    ref_seq.squeeze(dim=1),
    repeats=int(L),
    dim=0,
)
```

However, this feels like a bug or at least a missing feature from pytorch: why does `inp_seq.shape` produce CPU tensors when `inp_seq` is on the GPU?
I am currently using `torch 1.8.1+cu101`

Comment: I'm having the same issue, for what it's worth. In my circumstance, I'm tracing old models and trying to run them in pytorch 1.14.